# Json vs Var usage in Ballerina

Tags: ballerina

If we have a json variable declared as below we can directly use .toString(). What is the logic behind?

```
json a1 = {"a":"a", "b":"b"};
string c = a1.toString();
```

But if we have a var declared as below we can't use .toString().

```
table dt ;
...
var jsonConversionRet = <json>dt;
jsonConversionRet.toString(); // throws error "function invocation on type 'json|error' is not supported"
```

Comment: function invocation on type 'json|error' is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ballerina type conversion returns an union type of desired type and error type.
See: [union type](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/union-type.html). That means the type inferred by Ballerina compiler is 
json|error.

You have to use a match and handle the success path and failure path explicitly.

```
var jsonConversionRet = <json>dt;
match (jsonConversionRet) {
    json j => j.toString();
    error err => io:println("error: " + err.message);
}
```